# java.lang.AssertionError: CALL 'public final fun <get-currentComposer> () when using Jetpack Compose in non-root module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

After integrating compose in my multi-module project the following compiler error appears after when running `compileDebugKotlin` in the module where compose is enabled. The issue only appears when having compose code (functions annotated with `@Compose`) in a non-root module. When I move the code in the root module everything works fine.

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: CALL 'public final fun <get-currentComposer> (): androidx.compose.runtime.Composer<*> declared in androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer<*> origin=FOR_LOOP_ITERATOR

    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.visitCall(ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.transformChildren(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitMemberAccess(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionAccess(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:198)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.visitCall(ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.transformChildren(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitMemberAccess(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionAccess(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:198)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.visitCall(ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:117)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBody.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBody.transform(IrBody.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFunction.transformChildren(IrFunction.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitPackageFragment(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.transform(IrFile.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.transformChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.lower(ComposerIntrinsicTransformer.kt:38)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade$doGenerateFiles$1.invoke(JvmBackendFacade.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade$doGenerateFiles$1.invoke(JvmBackendFacade.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFiles(JvmBackendFacade.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:647)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:210)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:371)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:249)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:602)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1644)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

The compose code is correct and compose was integrated correctly. What does this error mean?